# Why does not it work a join in loopback?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

I inherited model

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "plural": "users",
  "base": "User",
  "relations": {
    "roles": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Role",
      "foreignKey": "principalId",
      "through": "RoleMapping"
    }
  },
```

And create hook, for saving role with user

```
 UserModel.afterRemote('create', (context, user, next) => {
        let body = context.req.body;
        if (!body.hasOwnProperty('roleId')) {
          next();
        }
        Role.findById(body.roleId)
          .then(role => {
            if (!role){
              next();
            }
            return user.roles.add(role);
          })
          .then(roleMapping => {
            next();
          });
      });
```

And record successfuly added to db(mongo), but while request GET

```
/api/users?access_token={}[include]=roles
```

record not joined, why?

Answer (score -1):

your querystring is wrong 
the include filter should be

`/api/users?access_token={}&filter[include]=roles`

([include filter](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Include-filter.html))